# Cache for everybody except staff members

Tags: django, django-caching

I have a django site where I want to stick an "admin bar" along the top of every non-admin page for staff members. It would contain useful things like page editing tools, etc.

The problem comes from me using the `@cache_page` decorator on lots of pages. If a normal user hits a page, the cached version comes up without the admin bar (even for admin users) and if an admin hits the page first, normal users see the admin bar.

I *could* tediously step through the templates, adding regional cache blocks but there are a lot of templates, and life is altogether too short.

Ideally, there would be a way of telling the caching to ignore cache get/set requests from admin users... But I don't know how to best implement that.

How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: Not exactly the same problem, but similar: http://www.holovaty.com/writing/django-two-phased-rendering/

Comment: That is genius but it does look like a headache to implement. Looks like an excellent idea for high-volume pages that need personalising.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't tell you the entire truth.. The only logged in people are staff members. Everybody else is anonymous.

Digging through the [cache middleware source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/middleware/cache.py) (what `@cache_page` uses) I found the `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY` setting!

I believe this should fix things for me.

Comment: FYI - ``CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY`` setting was deprecated in Django 1.6, because apparently it was 'largely ineffective': https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#cache-middleware-anonymous-only-setting